# How to select specific string between a line with sed or awk, without print the whole line

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I want to select a specific string within a line in an big txt file with sed or awk. But I got always the whole line and each line is 100.000+ characters long.

I got for example:

```
</div><div class="follow   withFollow" id="user-id-1234567890"> <a href="/app/users/id-1234567890/test/ </div><div class="follow   withFollow" id="user-id-0123456789"> <a href="/app/users/id-0123456789/test/" 12345678990 1234877890 1234767890 1245456780 123456790 withFollow" id="user-id-9873456789">
```

The only thing I want is the numbers in:

```
withFollow" id="user-id-1234567890">, withFollow" id="user-id-0123456789">, withFollow" id="user-id-9873456789">
```

output:

```
1234567890
0123456789
9873456789
```

I tried a lot like:

```
sed -n '/**user-id-**/,/**">**/p' FILE
awk '/**user-id-**/,/**">**/p' FILE
awk '/**user-id-**/,/**">**/p' FILE | grep -Eo "[0-9]{1,15}" > output.txt
```

With the last one I got only other numbers in the same line, so not only within `id="user-id-1234567890">`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use grep:

```
$ grep -oP 'user-id-\K[^"]*' file
1234567890
0123456789
9873456789
```

Or if you only want to match digits:

```
grep -oP 'user-id-\K\d*' file
```

Comment: Got a error with: grep -oP 'user-id-\K[^"]*' file usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

Comment: @patrick So your grep doesn't support the `-P` option... What OS are you on, and what version of grep do you have installed?

Comment: grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD - MAC OSX

Comment: @patrick: Then I don't think that you can do it in a single grep command. Try this pipeline: `grep -o 'user-id-[^"]*' file | grep -o '[0-9]*'`